# On proving $\ker(TT^*+T^*T)=\ker(T^*)\cap \ker(T)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:V\to V$ be a linear transformation of finite dimensional inner product space.

I want to show that  $$\ker(TT^*+T^*T)=\ker(T^*)\cap \ker(T).$$

I showed already that $$\ker(T^*)\cap \ker(T)\subseteq \ker(TT^*+T^*T).$$

How do I showing the other inclusion?

($T^*$ is adjoint of $T$)

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $x \in \ker(TT^* + T^*T)$. Then $TT^*x = - T^*Tx$, hence
\begin{align*}
  \|Tx\|^2 &= (Tx,Tx)\\
           &= (x, T^*Tx)\\
           &= -(x, TT^*x)\\
           &= -(T^*x, T^*x)\\
           &= -\|T^*x\|^2
\end{align*}
As both $\|Tx\|^2$ and $\|T^*x\|^2$ are non-negative, this is only possible for $Tx = T^*x = 0$.

Answer (score 7):

To prove the other inclusion : for $x \in \ker(TT^*+T^*T)$, 
\begin{eqnarray}
0 &=& (TT^*x + T^*Tx,x) \\
&=& (TT^*x,x) + (T^*Tx,x) \\
&=& (T^*x,T^*x) + (Tx,Tx) \\
&=& \lVert T^*x \rVert^2 + \lVert Tx \rVert^2
\end{eqnarray}
And thus $Tx = T^*x = 0$.